Which carriers on a multi-segment flight need to have interlining agreements for baggage to be checked through?
In the answer to Which airlines need to hold interline agreements with each other in order for an itinerary to be bookable?, there's a great example given for a ticket involving

A ticketing carrier TT
Operating carriers XX and ZZ, where
TT has interline arrangements with both XX and ZZ, but
But XX and ZZ don't have any such agreements with each other.

In that scenario, baggage can usually not be checked through.
Extending that scenario to a leg involving three segments, operated by carriers XX, YY, and ZZ, which of these need to have an interline agreement for baggage for a traveler to be able to check their baggage through for their entire leg?
Obviously TT needs to have an agreement with all of XX, YY, and ZZ for the ticket to be issued that way in the first place, but who else needs to have one for this to work?

XX with YY, as well as XX with ZZ, as the carrier accepting the baggage and entering it into the systems of all subsequent carriers?
XX with YY, and YY with ZZ, for the actual baggage transfer coordination to work out?
Both of the above, i.e. both each pair of delivering and receiving carrier along the leg, as well as the carrier accepting the luggage with each subsequent one, to enter the bag into their systems?


That seems like a rather convoluted use case and I don't think a general answer exist. Interlining agreement are not black and white and, vary in detail and scope, and are hard to get info about. For any specific itinerary you will need to ask the ticketing carrier and sometimes  you only find out at the airport.

Practically, I can definitely imagine all kinds of limiting factors and edge cases. I was just wondering if there were any relevant ICAO guidelines or industry practices for the general/theoretical case.
After all, reducing air travel planning problems to well-known results from computer science and graph theory has somewhat of a tradition :) http://www.demarcken.org/carl/papers/ITA-software-travel-complexity/ITA-software-travel-complexity.pdf
